# How to apply Command Design pattern with Dependency Injection using Generic Class?

Tags: .net-core, design-patterns, solid-principles

i want to apply command Design pattern with dependency Injection in the following situation: i have three types of reports in my system (SubscriptionReport, SalesReport, SpechialistReport)  so i created one interface `IReportService`

```
public interface IReportService<T> where T: class
    {
        public Task<GenericResponse<List<T>>> GetReport(string searchKey, DateTime from, DateTime to);

    }
```

and to apply  OCP i have implemented the `GetReport` function tree times for (SubscriptionReport, SalesReport, SpechialistReport)

```
public class SpechialistReportService : IReportService<SpechialistReportDTO>
    {
        public Task<GenericResponse<List<SpechialistReportDTO>>> Report(string searchKey, DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); // to be implemented later
        }
    }

 public class SubscriptionReportService : IReportService<SubscriptionReportDTO>
    {
        public Task<GenericResponse<List<SubscriptionReportDTO>>> Report(string searchKey, DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); // to be implemented later
        }
    }
 public class SalesReportService : IReportService<SalesReportDTO>
    {
        public Task<GenericResponse<List<SalesReportDTO>>> Report(string searchKey, DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); // to be implemented later
        }
    }
```

after that i have added the dependency

```
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IReportService<SpechialistReportDTO>), typeof(SpechialistReportService));
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IReportService<SubscriptionReportDTO>), typeof(SubscriptionReportService));
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IReportService<SalesReportDTO>), typeof(SalesReportService));
```

the problem is in calling the dependency in the controller constructor

```
 private readonly IEnumerable<IReportService> _reportService; // Should be IReportService<dont know what class should i specify here>

        public ReportController(IReportService<T> reportService)
        {
            this._reportService = reportService;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance,

Comment: Based on what do you know the class to replace T?

Comment: @Den Thanks for your concern but i solved it by removeing the Generic Class and add the marker interface to the DTOs classes

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved this problem by removing the Generic and adding marker interface to the DTOs classes

```
public interface ReportRoot 
    {
    }

  public class SubscriptionReportDTO : ReportRoot
    {
        // Some data here
    }


public class SalesReportDTO: ReportRoot
        {
            // Some data here
        }
```

In ReportService Interface

```
public interface IReportService
    {
        public Task<GenericResponse<List<ReportRoot>>> Report();

    }
public class SubscriptionReportService : IReportService    {
        public async Task<GenericResponse<List<ReportRoot>>> Report()
        {
            List<ReportRoot> subscriptionReportDTO = new List<ReportRoot>();
            SubscriptionReportDTO test = new SubscriptionReportDTO();
            test.SalesTax = "1000";
            subscriptionReportDTO.Add(test);
            return new GenericResponse<List<ReportRoot>>("1", subscriptionReportDTO.Count, "Success", subscriptionReportDTO);

        }
    }



  public class SalesReportService : IReportService    {
            public async Task<GenericResponse<List<ReportRoot>>> Report()
            {
                List<ReportRoot> salesReportDTO = new List<ReportRoot>();
                SalesReportDTO test = new SalesReportDTO ();
                test.SalesTax = "1000";
                salesReportDTO .Add(test);
                return new GenericResponse<List<ReportRoot>>("1", salesReportDTO.Count, "Success", salesReportDTO );

            }
        }
```

In controller

```
private readonly IEnumerable<IReportService> _reportService;

public ReportController(IEnumerable<IReportService> reportService)
{
    this._reportService = reportService;
}
```